# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to the client

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Dear whoever closed this: the solutions to that other question all involve making changes to the MySQL server, which I very specifically said I cannot do. So that question doesn't provide me a solution.

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database with utf8mb4 as the character set using the following in PHP 5.6

```
<?php
require '../env.php';
try {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$mysql_hostname.';dbname='.$mysql_database.';charset=utf8mb4';
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

I cannot change the MySQL server's character set. I get a similar error with mysqli. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your server doesn't seem to support `utf8mb4` (perhaps it an old version). You can obtain a list of supported encodings with this query: `SHOW CHARACTER SET`

Comment: `utf8mb4` is supported by mysql since version 5.5.3, and PHP 5.6 is EOL since  31 Dec 2018. I'd recommend you to upgrade both.

Comment: @digijay Yes, in a perfect world one wouldn't get handed old legacy applications to work with.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Actually, I know that's the correct character set for the MySQL server.

Comment: There isn't really a correct one, there's a list of several supported values. I can't recall when `utf8mb4` was introduced but it wasn't present in earlier server versions. If you can't use it, you'll need to switch back to `utf8`.

Comment: I changed the dupe target to a more relevant question

Comment: @YourCommonSense I still think there has to be a simpler solution to this than upgrading the entire codebase to PHP 7 . . .

Comment: yes. use utf8 instead of utf8mb4